# Java ArrayList Comparator Implementation

Tags: java

I have a issue to implementing the sorting what i did i created a class

```
 @Override
    public int compare(Object object1, Object object2) {

        try {
            Method method = object1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getStampDate");
            Date value = (Date) method.invoke(object1);

            Method method1 = object1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getStampDate");
            Date value1 = (Date) method.invoke(object2);

            //Date stamepDate1 = fetchStampDate(object1 );
            //Date stamepDate2 = fetchStampDate(object2);

            if(value != null && value1 != null )
            return compare(value, value1);
        }
```

But when i am calling

```
public void columnsList(List<TableRecord> records){
    Collections.sort(records, new StampDateComparator());
}
```

Comparator called only one time what i am expecting , `TableRecord` contain a date variable this sort method will sort on the basis of date but Comparator call only one time what i am doing wrong?

For Testing i added two record in the list

```
List<TableRecord> records = new ArrayList<TableRecord>();
records.add(new MyClass());
records.add(new MyClass1());
```

But this called one time only

Comment: How many records are in your list?

Comment: It's called once per item in the List.

Comment: @KevinBowersox, I'm sorry but I would like to know how it depends on the number of records in the list

Comment: @PrasadKharkar If there is one record in the list it will only execute once.  Just checking for a very basic problem or misunderstanding

Comment: Record can be 1 more than one but when i debug it called one time only

Comment: Why would it be called more than one time, since your list only contains 2 items to compare? Lets' say you have to compare 2 persons by height, do you need to do more than 1 comparison to know who's the tallest?

Comment: If you have `List<TableRecord>` then the comaprator should also be `Comparator<TableRecord>`, or do you plan to have some casting as part of `// Some logic` ...

Comment: i added logic of comaprtor

Answer (score 0):

To compare two items you need only single comparsion. Just try with three items and if it will be called 2 times, then I think, that everything works properly.

Comment: Yes right but i am getting sort method can you check sorting logic added more code

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two items in the list, then it is valid that it will invoke the method only once, as in the first compare itself it is sorted.

**The sorting algorithm in Collections.sort is a modified mergesort** (in which the merge is omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the lowest element in the high sublist). This algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n) performance. This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place.

Comment: Thanks can you check Sort logic in comartor its look buggy to me

Comment: Refer this grepcode. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29